# What is the correlation between string length and string substring methods?

Tags: java, string

I basically had to make a program that returns the number of times that the string "code" appears anywhere in the given string, except we'll accept any letter for the 'd', so "cope" and "cooe" count for my APCS class, I had no problems with the code except for the parameters of the for loop, the `i<str.length()-3` in particular. It works fine, but only after I kept subtracting random numbers arbitrarily from the length. I really want to know what the correlation between that and the rest of the code is so it isn't just a guess and check thing for me. I don't want to get in the habit of doing that.

```
public int countCode(String str) {
  int times = 0;
  for(int i =0;i<str.length()-3;i++){
  if(str.substring(i,i+2).equals("co") && str.substring(i+3,i+4).equals("e"))
      times++;
  }
  return times;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search pattern is 4 characters long.  The last character of the string is at index `.length() - 1`.  Therefore the last index where the pattern can start is 3 characters earlier at `.length() - 4`.  You used a less than comparison with `.length - 3`.  So the last iteration of the loop is at this value.  It's correct.

A little sketch can help in cases like this:

```
                |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  Pattern
      ... | L-5 | L-4 | L-3 | L-2 | L-1 |  String (L==str.length)
         ... < L-3 ...|                    Iterations
```

Comment: So basically it is just how far away it can logically be from the end of the string since it's 4 characters long of a search, and it's .length()-3 because of how substring will works at 0 instead of 1, it is -3 instead of -4, correct?

Answer (score 3):

The correlation is that the substring has to fit inside the source string. You are calling `str.substring(i, i+2)`. Now let's say that your string is 5 characters long. This means the first index inside the string is 0, and the last one is 4. Now imagine that `i` is equal to 3.

When you call `substring(i, i+2)`, you are really calling `substring(3, 5)`. The `substring` method takes a start index and an end index. Your end index turns out to be 5, which is illegal because it's outside of the string the last index of which is 4.

So you should really be checking `i < str.length() - searchString.length() + 1` instead of `i < str.length() - 3`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `i < str.length() - (searchString.length() - 1);`?  Or equivalently `i < str.length() - searchString.length() + 1;`?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a regular expression match. Using `String#substring` is needlessly complicated for this scenario. A better approach is to use `Pattern#matcher` as follows:

```
public static int countCode(String s) {
    Pattern codepattern = Pattern.compile("co.e");
    Matcher codematcher = codepattern.matcher(s);
    int count = 0;
    while (codematcher.find()) count++;
    return count;
}
```

As you can see, `find()` will keep finding the regex until the end of the given string. For example, given `String s = "This core supports all the code. Everyone comes to the core, for the cool stuff is all coded in here.";`, the above method returns `5`.

*Edit*: I realize this is not exactly what you had asked, but I thought this might help you.

Comment: Definitely helps even though I have no clue what half those methods do, I will definitely try to get myself familiar with them now.

Answer (score 0):

Gene is spot on, but consider this regex-based alternative:

```
int times = str.replaceAll("co[a-z]e", "xxxxx").length() - str.length();
```

It's all done in one line and you let the regex engine do the heavy lifting.